# Ошибка "HDLCompiler:806-Line 33: Syntax error near "entity"." Как ее победить?

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, vhdl

Доброго дня всем. Такой вопрос. Вылетает ошибка "ERROR:HDLCompiler:806-Line 33: Syntax error near "entity"."
  Синтаксис написан верно (вроде). Смысловая составляющая тоже вроде есть. Подскажите, что мне делать пожалуйста.
P.s. еще очень замучала ошибка "design is empty". Если кто знает, что с ней делать, тоже была бы неплоха информация.
Спасибо.

```
entity massive is
    port ( 
            clk     : in std_logic;
            reset : in std_logic;
            sin     : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0));
end massive;

architecture Behavioral of massive is
    type my_type is array (0 to 16) of signed (14 downto 0);
    signal x : my_type;
    signal y : my_type;
    signal z : my_type;
    signal j : my_type := ("001111111001000", "001101111100010", "001101101101010", "000110111101010", "000011011111100", 
                                                                    "000001101111110", "000000110111111", "000000011100000", "000000001110000", "000000000111000",
                                                                     "000000000011100", "000000000001110", "000000000000110", "000000000000011", "000000001000010",
                                                                     "000000000000010", "000000000000001");
    signal x1 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal y1 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal z1 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

begin
process(clk, reset)                                                                   
begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if reset <= '1' then
                for i in 0 to 15 loop
                    if (z(i) >= '0') then 
                        x1(i) <= x(i+1) - (y(i+1)/2**i);
                        y1(i) <= y(i+1) + (x(i+1)/2**i);
                        z1(i) <= z(i) - j(i);
                    else
                        x1(i) <= x(i+1) + (y(i+1)/2**i);
                        y1(i) <= y(i+1) - (x(i+1)/2**i);
                        z1(i) <= z(i) + j(i);
                    end if;
                sin <= y1;
                end loop;
            end if;
        end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 0):

Не увидел в листинге присутствия объявления используемых библиотек
Ожидал увидеть начало в таком виде:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity massive is
```

Заранее хотел бы предупредить вас, что если Вы используете обозначение "**" как функцию степени - боюсь вас расстроить, все не так просто. А еще циклы это тоже непросто. VHDL - это язык описания аппаратуры и совершенно отличается от языков программирования. 
Судя по коду, Вы пишите CORDIC, я прав?